# element of a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

Can someone please explain In Java how do you find middle element of a linked list in single pass?

I have googled it, but cannot seem to find a simple explanation on how to code it.

Comment: I guess google had no answer because the question is trivial. lists have a `get(int position)`. Also, you don't wanna use a LinkedList if you operate in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add("foo");
list.add("bar");
list.add("baz");
String middle = list.get(list.size()/2);
System.out.println(middle); // bar
```

The call to assign `middle` will pass through half of the list during the `get` call.

As pointed out in the comments, the middle is the worst place to operate on a `LinkedList`. Consider using another variation, such as `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a sort of trick question that you see on lists of possible interview questions.

One solution would be to have two pointers to step through the list, one taking steps of two and one taking steps of one.

When the pointer that is taking two steps at a time reaches the end of the list, the one taking only one step will be halfway through.

I doubt that this practice is really useful though..

good luck!

Answer (score -2):

Since it's a LinkedList, you won't be able to find out its size until after the first (and only) pass.  To find the middle element, you need to know two things; what index is at the middle, and what is the value of the element at that index.  Finding the middle index is easy--just make one pass through the list, keeping a counter of how many nodes there are.  As you do this, you'll need to keep track of each element in a separate data structure, perhaps an ArrayList, since you're only allowed one pass through the LinkedList.  Once you're done, half the counter to find the middle index, and return the ArrayList element at that index.

The pseudo code looks like this:

```
int count
ArrayList elements

for each node in LinkedList:
  count++
  elements.append(node)

middleIndex = count/2
middleElement = elements.getIndex(middleIndex)

return middleElement
```

Of course, you'll need to take care of the case where there isn't a single middle element.

Comment: Until you recall that any sane implementation caches the count of elements.

Comment: like Java's `LinkedList` does... :)

Comment: and copying the `LinkedList` to an `ArrayList` just to find the middle element kinda defeats the purpose...